# Perfectly overlapping round divs

Tags: css, html, hover, geometry

I have a list which has round elements in it. They have a image in the background and on hover the other div is supposed to become visible as an overlay. It works so far, however there is still a visible border, indicating that the hovered div is not perfectly overlaying the other rounded element.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="hover"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="hover"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="hover"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 140px;
}
li {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 70px;
     background: url(http://www.nationalflaggen.de/media/flags/flagge-thailand.gif);
}
.hover {
    border-radius: 70px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
.hover:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}
```

I added a fiddle since I really don't know how to make them perfectly overlapping.

Thanks for your help.

UPDATED THE FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/pL9Aa/1

Comment: just make the overlaying div larger than the underlaying div

Comment: or hide the underlaying one on hover.

Comment: I edited my post. The underlying image has to be visible since the overlay is transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a sub-pixel problem -- the browser does a bunch of math to determine the smoothness of a curve using square pixels. And sometimes it doesn't render how you might expect.

You can simply remove the border-radius rule from the :hover pseudo class if you are keeping it transparent.

```
.hover {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/pL9Aa/2/)

If it needs to be round, I would override your image using the same element, instead of a nested element, like so:

```
li:hover {
    background: white;
}
```

[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/pL9Aa/6/)

Comment: Added accommodation for keeping it round.

Comment: I forgot to make clear that the image need to be visible since the overlay is transparent. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could add:

```
li:hover {
    background:none;
}
```

to ensure that the background on the li is gone.

It's weird though - does look like a rendering bug.

Assuming that you are going to have text or other content in the overlay, it's worth noting that setting the background to be slightly transparent (e.g. rgba(255,255,255,0.8)) makes the rendering error less noticeable.

Comment: sorry I didn't make it clear, the background needs to be visible since the overlaying div is transparent

Answer (score 0):

Just change `#hover`s `border-radius: 62px;`

Comment: this makes no sense, sorry

Comment: in your css change the border radius from 70 to 62, simple

Comment: But then it isn't completely round anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If your hover is only meant to cover the element, you do not need to put a border-radius on the hover element. Simply removing that line will resolve your issue:

```
.hover {
   width: 140px;
   height: 140px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pL9Aa/3/

Comment: It is supposed to be transparent, therefore it needs to be round since the background of everything is an image.

Answer (score 0):

If in the production envirionment you can actually use a background color, you could also use a `box-shadow`

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j4NFB/

```
.hover:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;
}
```

Comment: It's close but still not perfect

Comment: You can keep increasing the size of the 1px part.  the only problem is  if you are actually using a background image for the overlay rather than a color.

Comment: If you increase it than it will still show the border where the underlying image ends. I guess there is no way to achieve that.